# How to use threading to update a DataTable which tends to change dynamically by Main Thread?

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a dataTable which used to filled on click of a button say 'Search'. On this click when dataTable filled with data. I am creating a new thread which updates at dataTable data. But User again clicked on search button. Now that dataTable again filled with New data while a thread was already updating that dataTable. On Search click the code again creates a new thread and starts updating that changed dataTable. Here I am having error as: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. Please suggest a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check if InvokeRequired on the control you're updating and then do Invoke or BeginInvoke if necessary
2. Disable button and/or disable new update if update is already in progress

For updating DataGridView's DataSource:

```
if(DGV.InvokeRequired)
DGV.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
{
     DGV.DataSource= currentDataTable;
}));
else DGV.DataSource= currentDataTable;
```

If you're updating from another thread and setting currentDataTable there, maybe you shouold consider creating an event that'll fire and update your GUI when your update is done (or work completed - if you're using BackgroundWOrker) - the Invoke won't be necessary then.

Comment: Hi @Arie, Thanks for suggestion. In my case the control which I am updating is DataTable. Can you please give me a code sample for it.

Comment: Do you have any data bindings set that bind your DataTable to your controls? From my experience this exception is usually thrown when you try to update some UI element from thread other than your UI thread (meaning your background thread in some way, direct or indirect, tries to change the UI)

Comment: Yes that dataTable is datasource for a Grid Control and I am updating the data of that dataTable in another thread while Grid Control has been assigned dataTable as datasource by Main Thread.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign the search button to

```
btn.Enabled = false;
```

when clicking on it and invoke a method the will reEnable it when the search is over

if you don't want the button to be disabled you can use this code

```
private BackgroundWorker trd;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (trd != null)
   {
      trd.CancelAsync();
   }

   trd = new BackgroundWorker();
   trd.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(trd_DoWork);
   trd.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
   trd.RunWorkerAsync();
}

public void trd_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     // Your search code
}
```

that way you abort the thread and restart it. the search is stopped at the middle and won't edit the values with another background worker. the background worker is editing the values meaning there wont be cross threading, as you know no other thread but the UI thread can edit the UI

Comment: Ok but what if I don't want user to restrict by disabling the search button i.e. I want the previous thread stop and the new thread to work on new updated dataTable?

Comment: Hi @No Idea For Name, Thanks a lot. It worked for me. But my issue was different as even after implementing the above code, I was having same issue but after analyzing my code, I found a line in which I was refereshing the Grid each time I was updating a single row in that DataTable. When I removed that line. It is working fine.